# What is the direction of magnetic field lines?

Tags: magnetic-fields

Ok, so I was studying about magnetism. And
the book mentioned:

> Magnetic field lines are directed from *south* pole towards the *north* pole and thus a closed and continuous curve is formed.

Here is an image from the book:

[image: image of the book's page]

Then the diagrams indicated that magnetic field lines are directed from *north* pole towards the *south* pole.

Here are the diagrams:

[image: image of the diagrams]

Now which one do I believe? Both the images are from Selina Publishers' Physics...

Thanks in advance for support..

Comment: Magnetic field lines are closed loops. Inside the magnet they run from South Pole to North; outside they run from North Pole to South.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Now which one do I believe?

You believe both. They are both correct and they do not contradict each other at all.

The text says that the lines go from south to north inside the magnet. The images show the lines going from north to south outside the magnet. The fact that magnetic field lines form continuous closed loops means that south to north inside the magnet implies north to south outside and vice versa.

Answer (score 1):

*Outside* the magnet the lines of both the  ${\bf B}$ and ${\bf H}$ fields are directed from the north pole to the south pole.  The quoted text in your first image refers to to *inside* the magnet where the lines of ${\bf B}$ are directed from the south pole to the north pole so as to form closed loops. (Mathematically this is because ${\rm div\,}{\bf B}=0$, but if you are just learning the subject this statement won't mean much to you).  The inside   lines of ${\bf H}$
however run from the north pole to the south, so they are opposite to the lines of ${\bf B}$. Unfortunately both ${\bf B}$ and ${\bf H}$ are called the "magnetic field" in casual talk.

The ${\bf H}$ field is defined as
$$
{\bf H}=\frac 1 {\mu_0} {\bf B}-{\bf M}
$$
where ${\bf M}$ is the *magnetization* or more precisely the magnetic dipole moment per unit volume of the magnetic material.  It's a mesure of how strongly the magentic material is magnetized.

Both  ${\bf B}$ and ${\bf H}$  are useful,  because they  satisfy simple equations.

Answer (score 0):

The diagram because they are directed from north to south

Comment: Some explanation please...

Comment: The Direction is taken as a convention and the magnetic field lines are also just imaginary though they are useful and if you keep a compass near near a magnet then the Direction in which needles north pole points is the direction of magnetic field lines.

Comment: Hmm... Fine. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The direction of the magnetic field lines is the direction of the B-field. By convention they go from North to South.

Sometimes it seems confusing. Let's put a wire under a compass, so that it (the wire) has direction N-S, and the conventional current flows to North. The resultant magnetic field from the wire acting on the needle, according to the right hand rule, is directed to east. And the needle is deflected to the east indeed.

But what happened was a sum of 2 vectors: $\mathbf B_{earth} + \mathbf B_{wire}$.

We must conclude that in the case of the earth, the field lines go from (approximated geographic) South to North. And that the magnetic pole close to the geographic north pole is in reality a magnetic south pole.

That way it is explained why the needle deflects to east. Its field lines aligns in a way to be parallel to the net external field and with opposing direction.

Answer (score 0):

"By convention", says it all. It is not an observed law of nature. The direction of magnetic flux is unknowable since you can not separate the two poles. You can only state the fact that opposite poles attract and similar poles repel because that is what we observe in nature. Therefore, the direction of magnetic flux is a fictitious man-made "convention"... ie something agreed upon by a group of people.